# Comparing an NSArray of NSStrings with another NSArray of NSStrings

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstring, nsarray

I have two `NSArray`s each containing `NSString`s. I need to test whether the two arrays are equal. In this instance, equality means not that the arrays contain the same objects, but that each object returns true for `isEqualToString` when compared its counterpart. The arrays are also not equal if one contains more items than the other, or the order of the items is different.

Can I assume `isEqualToArray` won't help me here?

Similarly, I don't see an approach using `NSSet` that would fulfill all of the criteria.

How might I test the equality of these two arrays?

Comment: Look at the docs. `isEqualToArray:` uses `isEqual:` on each pair of objects.

Comment: Does isEqual always return the same as isEqualToString for NSStrings?

Comment: If it doesn't, then `NSString` is broken. Again, look at the docs for `isEqualToString:`.

Comment: I've read the NSObject protocol and I see that each NSObject defines what it means to be equal. I think what's getting in my way is why isEqualToString exists if isEqual does the same thing.

Comment: @BenPackard: `isEqualToString` is a *tiny bit* faster than `isEqual` if both objects are strings (because the method doesn't check at runtime to see if they are both strings).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The docs for `isEqualToArray` state:

> Two arrays have equal contents if they each hold the same number of objects and objects at a given index in each array satisfy the `isEqual:` test.

That seems like it fits your criteria.

Comment: So does [obj1 isEqual:obj2] return the same as [obj1 isEqualToString:obj2] if obj1 and obj2 are both NSString?

Comment: Be aware that isEqual when applied to NSStrings returns YES if the two object are NSStrings without actually comparing the contents. To be sure that two arrays contains the same strings in the same order you will need to loop through each using isEqualToString:

Comment: @MyTallest: `-[NSString isEqual:]` will call `-[NSString isEqualToString:]` if both objects are strings; otherwise, it will return `NO`.